# Kettle - JSON Input fail on unparseable date

Tags: json, date, parsing, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to parse a date field "Wed 9-16-15 14:50:13 CDT" using "EEE M-d-yy  HH:mm:ss zzz" yet I'm getting unparseable date. I'm using all the correct symbols according to the pentaho site.

Comment: kettle is written on java, so u should look into JavaAPI to find out how to parse date using java.text.SimpleDateFormat (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I succeseed to solve problem. You just have to set locale. 
Another thing set lenient to false ('N')
[image]

Information is taken from here 
http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?160099-Cannot-parse-date-in-string-to-date-format

Comment: This may fix for the 16th, however I'm not getting it to pass following that structure for Thu 9-22-15 09:00:00 CDT, so it seems day specific

Comment: If u will try to set lenient to true 'Y'. Then is works, but cuts the timezone.

Comment: Actually the issue there was due to a mismatch between the day of the week and the day given by the M-d-y combination.